# autoload con clases extendidas, herencia

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente `autoload`

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register('_autoload');
define('DS','/');

function _autoload( $class ) {

    $class = ROOT  . str_replace("\\",DS,$class) . '.php';

    if(!file_exists($class)){
        echo "Error al cargar la clase " . $class;
        die();
    }else{
        require_once($class);
    }
}
```

Esto funciona perfecto en clases sin herencia, el problema radica cuando una clase hereda de otra, el `autoload` carga la clase madre/padre y por ende no me carga la clase que quiero, aquí un ejemplo;

`TaskController.php`

```
use Models\Tasks\Task;

class TasksController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $tasks = new Task();
        $data['tasks'] = $tasks->showAllTasks();
        $data['cantidad_tareas'] = $tasks->tasks_number_by_status(0);
        $this->setData($data); //envia datos a la vista
        $this->render("index",'Index Page'); //Renderiza la vista con un titulo
    }
}
```

`TaskModel.php`

```
namespace Models\Tasks;

class Task extends Model
{
........
```

La siguiente pantalla es una pantalla personalizada que tengo para cuando sucedan errores dentro deme mi framework, como podrán ver dice que el problema esta en la clase `Model.php' pero la clase que se quiere cargar es 'TaskModel.php';

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es crear un `autoload` que sea capaz de cargar todas las clases sin ningún problema así como cabemos optimizamos el rendimiento ya que solo se incluirán las clases o archivos de los que hagamos uso.

Comment: Que sucede si renombras tu clase Task y le pones TaskModel extends Model???

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas Obtengo el mismo resultado, el `autoload` esta cargando la clase de la que hereda, pasa de largo por la clase que le he pedido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema en si es que no tenia el `namespace` declarado en la clase `Model`;

```
namespace Core; //Simplemente lo agregue y funciono perfecto

class Model extends DataBase
{
 //....
}
```

Al no tener esto, el `autoloader` intentava cargar la clase padre/madre con el `namespace` de la clase hija.

Answer (score 1):

Albert yo tengo mi clase `Autoloader` escrita así y no tengo ningún problema:

```
<?php

class Autoloader
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loader'));
    }
    private function loader($className) {

        $str_path=realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
        $filename = $str_path .'/'. str_replace('\\', '/', $className) . ".class.php";

        include_once($filename);
    }
}
?>
```

Aquí hay algunas cosas:

- Uso `spl_autoload_register`
- En todas mi clases uso una *convención de nombre **de archivo***. O sea, todos mis archivos de clase están dentro de la misma carpeta `class` y terminan por `.class.php`

Por ejemplo tengo estas dos clases:

```
class Misa extends Liturgia{

    private $id;
    //...

    public function __construct(){

    }
    //Métodos
}
```

Y:

```
class Liturgia extends UtilStrings
{
    private $intLiturgia;
    private $intTiempo;
    //...

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function setTiempo($intTiempo){
                $this->intTiempo=$intTiempo;
    }

    //Más métodos
}
```

Ahora yo uso mi autoloader simplemente así:

```
require_once(CLASS_PATH."Autoloader.class.php");
$autoloader = new Autoloader();

$misa=new Misa();
#setTiempo y getTiempo son métodos de la clase padre Liturgia
$misa->setTiempo(5);
echo $misa->getTiempo();

#más aún, getCopyRight es un método de la clase UtilStrings, de la que extiende Liturgia
echo $misa->getCopyright(2013);
```

Este código funciona sin ningún tipo de problema.

Comment: Aunque esta no fue la solución en especifico a mi problema, me ha ayudado a dar con la solución, todo era problema de los `namespace` al no tenerlos implementados correctamente en la clase `Model` el `autoloader` usaba el `namespace` de la clase hija y así jamas encontraría la ruta correcta! Gracias padre! esto es para el framework que le comentaba la vez pasada.